# is there a way to write a function that takes the mean and std dev of 2 columns v1 and v2 by a specified id?

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm new to R and I'm trying to write a loop within a function so that it will return the mean and std dev of two different columns by a specific idea. My input should be (data, id). this is what I've come up with so far but I keep getting an error that says data argument is of the wrong type but I don't understand why.

```
i <- Final_File$id
V1 <- Final_File$Var1
V2 <- Final_File$Var2
newfunction <- function(data, i){
  x <- nrow(data)

  if(x<=1){
    print("Cannot take standard deviation, number of observations is equal to 1") }
  if(x>1) {
  data1 <- aggregate(cbind(V2, V2)~i, each(mean, sd))
  return(data1)
}
}
newfunction(Final_File, 1)
```

Comment: Where's the data? What is `each()` and what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just after the stdev and mean of the specified columns for the specified ID, do something like:

```
# get the bit of the data with that id
subdata <- subset(data, id == i)
# return these values however you like?
mean(subdata$V1)
mean(subdata$V2)
sd(subdata$V1)
sd(subdata$V2)
```

If you want to automagically loop over each ID in your dataframe all at once, you could do:

```
library(ddply)
ddply(data, .(id), summarize,
      mean1=mean(V1), mean2=mean(V2), sd1=mean(V1), sd2=mean(V2))
```

You can do something very similar with the `dplyr` and `data.table` packages; there are many questions covering this sort of manipulation.

(if you really want to stick to base R, you could do:

```
by(data, data$id, function (x) {
       # e.g. return your numbers as a vector
       return(c(mean(x$V1), mean(x$V2), sd(x$V1), sd(x$V2)) 
   })
```